# Matrices with real spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Assume you have a non-symmetric real square matrix all of whose eigenvalues are real. Can anything be said about it? Is it unitarily equivalent to a symmetric matrix?

EDIT: Is it at least *similar* to a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Re the last question: Clearly not in general. Consider a Jordan block of size greater than $1$ with one real eigenvalue.

Comment: Can anything be said? Well, if you choose the $n^2$ matrix elements from independent normal distributions, the probability that all eigenvalues are real is $2^{-n(n-1)/4}$ (a result due to Ginibre).

Comment: @ Geoff Robinson: Right, sorry. I have corrected my question.

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker: Nice result, thanks, but actually I was thinking of what to do *once* I am already given a matrix with real spectrum.

Comment: it is certainly _similar_ to a symmetric matrix, namely to the diagonal matrix containing the real eigenvalues on the diagonal. (ah, and omit the space after @ if you want the ping to work)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker How can it be similar to a symmetric ($=$ diagonalizable) matrix if it has large Jordan blocks? Say, $[[1,1],[0,1]]$ is certainly not similar to $I$.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: In what sense are you using the expression similaar? I thought $A$ and $B$ being similar meant $B = TAT^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $T$.

Comment: Are you familiar with pseudospectra?  Some of the basic examples in the theory show that real or not, eigenvalues are misleading when your matrix is not normal.

Comment: I meant to say :In which case A can not be similar to a diagonal matrix in general, as I implicitly said above

Comment: thank you for the comments --- I was just referring to the random matrix situation, where with probability 1 any matrix that has all real eigenvalues is similar to a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Following from @Noah's comment, there is a significant quantity of physics literature exploring this possibility.  See eg http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1082

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there is the following. Consider
$$
  \begin{equation}
    A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
                  0 & 1 \\
                  0 & 0 \\
                \end{array}
        \right)
  \end{equation}
$$
The matrix $A$ is non-symmetric with eigenvalues $\{0\}$. If $A$ were similar to a symmetric matrix $M$, then $A$ would be diagonalizable (because $M$ is), and we would have $A = 0$.

We can also look at
$$
  \begin{equation}
    B = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
                  1 & 1 \\
                  0 & 1 \\
                \end{array}
        \right)
  \end{equation}
$$
The eigenvalues of $B$ are $\{1\}$. If $B$ were similar to a symmetric matrix, then $B$ would equal the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Call $A$ this matrix. If you assume in addition that $A$ is diagonalisable, then $A$ is a product of two symmetric matrices $S_+S$ where $S_+$ is positive definite and the signs of the eigenvalues of $S$ are the signs of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Of course, you don't expect that $A$ be unitarily (= orthogonaly here) similar to a symmetric matrix, because it would be itself symmetric.

As said by many, if $A$ is not diagonalisable, it cannot be similar to a symmetric matrix.

Finally, Theorem 4.1.7 in R. Horn & C. Johnson says that every real matrix is a product of two hermitian matrices, but I don't know whether you may take real factors.

Comment: See H Stenzel:  ``Über die Darstellbarkeit einer Matrix als Produkt von zwei symmetrischen Matrizen, als Produkt von zwei alternierenden Matrizen und als Produkt yon einer symmetrisehen und einer alternienden Matrix''.  mathematische zeitschrift,  volume 15, Number 1, 1922. If I understood it right (my german very old...), it can be written as the product of two symmetrical matrices, one of it can be taken positive definite.